# Inverse object element order

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

What's the best way to inverse an order of json data?

```
var myObject = [
{"id":"001", "content":"content11111111111111"},
{"id":"002", "content":"content22222222222222"},
{"id":"003", "content":"content33333333333333"},
{"id":"004", "content":"content44444444444444"}
];

myJson = JSON.stringify(myObject);

var inverseMyJson = inverseOrder(myJson);

inverseMyJson ==>
[
{"id":"004", "content":"content44444444444444"},
{"id":"003", "content":"content33333333333333"},
{"id":"002", "content":"content22222222222222"},
{"id":"001", "content":"content11111111111111"}
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reverse it before you stringify it.

```
myObject.reverse();

myJson = JSON.stringify(myObject);
```

If you want to maintain the original order, then `.slice()` it first.

```
var reversed = myObject.slice().reverse();

myJson = JSON.stringify(reversed);
```